# Why does VS require not to use inline code?

Tags: c#

I just updated VS 2 days before, they added some features to VS. Here is the one of them:

[image: 1]

I'd read many documentations (from MSDN), sometimes they still use inline-code like that. I know that both of them give the same result but I don't know why it's a suggestion? Can you explain me why?

Current syntax:

```
return CreatedAtAction(nameof(RemoveFromContactList), new { succeeded = false });
```

Suggestion syntax:

```
var value = new { succeeded = false };
// We also have "base" keyword here
return base.CreatedAtAction(nameof(RemoveFromContactList), value);
```

Thank you!

**UPDATE:** (Based on @Damien_The_Unbeliever's answer):

[image: 2]

Comment: The short answer is: 'it doesn't'... An advice or suggestion is not a *requirement*.

Comment: @Fabjan Thanks! I got -1 because of that vocabulary ^^!

Comment: I can't see any -1...  ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same "Quick Action" icon will offer to convert an auto-implemented property into a full property (with backing field) and offer to convert a full property into an auto-implemented property.

If you're going to take these as *suggestions* then you'll spend the rest of your life converting that property back-and-forth between the two syntaxes.

These quick actions are for *possible* refactorings. It's up to *you* to decide whether you want to apply any of them and it's not suggesting that one form is *better* than the other.

In your example, for instance, I believe that after you introduce the local, a new option will become available to place the expression in-line and eliminate the variable again.

Comment: Exactly as you said: I have just tried and updated my question for the new result. Such a troll ^^!